# Why do my dropdown list dont show any options?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am writing a project with ASP.NET Core MVC. I want a hardcoded dropdown list where you can get alternatives to choose from which will be saved to my database that I have created with entity framework core. All I get is a dropdown itself, but no alternatives to choose from and I do not really understand why?

My controller where my hardcoded list are:

```
public IActionResult Create(int? id)
{
        TicketVM obj = new TicketVM();
        obj.ProjectList = _db.Projects.Select(i => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = i.Name,
            Value = i.Project_Id.ToString()
        });

        if (id == null)
        {
            return View(obj);
        }

        // Status List
        #region
        List<SelectListItem> statusList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        statusList.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = "Open",
            Text = "Open"
        });

        statusList.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = "Closed",
            Text = "Closed"
        });

        TicketVM ticketvm = new TicketVM()
        {
            StatusList = statusList
        };
        #endregion
        // Status List End

        obj.Ticket = _db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Ticket_Id == id);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(obj);
}
```

Here is my view model where I have my model for the list:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusList { get; set; }

public string TicketStatus { get; set; }
```

Here is my view where I have my dropdown list:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="TicketStatus" class="col-md-2"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select asp-for="TicketStatus" asp-items="@Model.StatusList" class="form-control">
            <option disabeld selected>
            --Select Status--
            </option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

My expected result would be that I would have a list where I could choose between open and closed

Comment: please show your controller action code too

Comment: Sorry! I have just added the whole controller code now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problematic code:

```
TicketVM ticketvm = new TicketVM()
{
     StatusList = statusList
};
```

Instead of setting the `StatusList` in the existing created vm object which is `obj` you have created a new one while object passed to view is `obj` not `ticketvm` so change your code to set the list in the `obj` like:

```
obj.StatusList = statusList;
```

You also need to do little more ordering of code at end to make it safe from carshing with run-time errors like:

```
if (obj == null)
{
    return NotFound();
}

obj.Ticket = _db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Ticket_Id == id);
obj.StatusList = statusList

return View(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you Ehsan! Solved my problem :)